# Print custom user fields

Tags: users

I want to display a custom field, and i've done it with this code

```
<?php
 global $user;

 $user_fields = user_load($user->uid);

 $customfield = $user_fields->field_navnn['und']['0']['value'];

 print  t("Custom field value is " . $customfield. ' ') ; 
?>
```

but it dosn't show when im logged out.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the global variable [$user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/user/7) which represents the logged-in user.

> An object representing the user currently visiting the site.
>
> Contains preferences and other account information for logged-in
>   users. When a user is not logged-in, the $user->uid property is set to
>   0.

You could use the user id from the URL on the user profile page by calling `arg(1)`.
Here is the possible fix for your code:

```
<?php
 $uid = arg(1);

 $user_fields = user_load($uid);

 $customfield = $user_fields->field_navnn['und']['0']['value'];

 print  t("Custom field value is " . $customfield. ' ') ; 
?>
```

I do not concern with your user profile template. This is just for your code fix.

Comment: Awesome it also worked for my other problem thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are doing:

```
      global $user;
```

and loading the fields of user which will load fields of only logged in user.

If you are printing it on user profile , then you can directly do the following in your `user-profile.tpl.php`.

```
  $customfield = $field_navnn[0]['value'];
```

and then print it.

Comment: I've done this
    <?php
      $firstname = $field_navnn['und']['0']['value'];
      print  t("Custom field value is " . $firstname) ; 
    ?>
but now it just gives me an error
Notice: Undefined variable: field_navnn in include() (line 67 of /home/www/modeindeks.com/sites/all/themes/modeindeks/templates/page--user.tpl.php).

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: After you define `global $user` put a condition `if ( $user->uid)` { } , then only do other actions inside braces . This will solve your error message.

Comment: And if you printing name of currently logged in user, how would you expect it to be printed when user has logged out ?? :)

Comment: I'm pretty new to all this can you please give an example

Comment: Yes I will but before that Can you explain me more about what exactly you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I want to print the name so when anonymous user visit the page they can see that field.
Every client has a user page, and on that page the field will be displayed in an <h1> tag so it need to make that viewable by anonymous users, how can i achieve this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6801/discussion-between-sandesh-yadav-and-myrevenge)

Comment: I think you should create on template file `user-profile.tpl.php` in your themes/templates folder. And then `$customfield = $field_navnn[0]['value'];` and print it there. Can you please try this and let me know if it is workin. And dont foget to clear the cache after creating user-profile.tpl.php.

Comment: Yes lets du that